# rsync hosts file - permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, host

I wanted to sync the hosts file of one server with a few other servers. I am not having any problems with snycing other files.
Only the hosts file is not working. Also the error message is weird:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/etc/.hosts.NOmAJ8" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
```

the command I used was

```
rsync -a /etc/hosts user@host:/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my own.
I was the owner of the hosts file, but not of the /etc/ folder. Changing this solved my problem